# generic code to reverse alternate words in a sentence using python

Tags: python-3.x

can anyone please help on how to reverse alternate words in a sentence from the end using python.

note: do not use reversed()

eg:

aspire systems is in america

acirema in si systems eripsa

s = 'aspire systems is in america'

l = len(s) - 1

rev = ''

for i in range (0,l):

```
rev = rev + str(a[l])
l--
```

- i couldnt find a way to jump to "in" and print it.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Sorry, but with this sparse task description / rules - which by the way reads like homework - the error in the sample result is irritating me - bug or feature :-? try to reverse america per character correctly. It should read `acirema` no injected `a`, right? Out of curiosity, would you mind showing us your effort, so we help you push that to a solution? Thanks

Comment: Best edit the question not add comments with that intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we use split/join ?

```
s = 'aspire systems is in america'
li = s.split(' ') #["aspire", "systems", "is", "in", "america"]
#Reverse alternate words
for index in range (0,len(li),2): #0, 2, 4
    rev = ''
    for ch in li[index]: #'a', 's', 'p' ...
        rev = ch + rev
    li[index] = rev
#Now reverse the list of words
revli = []
for word in li:
    revli = word + revli
print ' '.join(revli) #Should print expected result
```

It should be equivalent to the following code, which uses reversed :

```
s = 'aspire systems is in america'
li = s.split(' ') #["aspire", "systems", "is", "in", "america"]
#Reverse alternate words
for index in range (0,len(li),2): #0, 2, 4
    li[index] = reversed(li[index])
print ' '.join(reversed(li)) #Should print expected result
```

I cannot test the code currently, please tell me if anything is missing or if you have any question concerning the code. If you are learning programming, it's important you fully understand it

EDIT: corrected join call

Comment: Thanks a lot Arthur  o/p - aciremainsisystemseripsa[]  . But the join doesnt seem to work . i will try it out. @Arthur

Comment: Ah, classic mistake, I reversed the join iterable and separator. It's ' '.join(revli) instead.